# how to print name using object reference?

Tags: swift

```
class Student {
    let name:String
    let age:Int
    init(name:String, age:Int){
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
    }
}

var students = [Student(name: "Luke", age: 23),Student(name: "Luis", age: 22)]
print(students.name)
```

Comment: did you try this `print(students[0].name)`? or you can use loop

Comment: You need to loop over the array `for student in students { print(student.name) }`

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this:

class Student {
    let name:String
    let age:Int
    
    init(name:String, age:Int){
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}

var students = [Student(name: "Luke", age: 23),
                Student(name: "Luis", age: 22)]


students.forEach({ student in
    print(student.name, student.age)
})
```

Output:

```
 Luke 23 
 Luis 22
```